# An XSD attribute to capture "source data field"

Tags: xsd

I have a domain model which is intended to generalise several source systems. As such, in certain cases the decision was made to overload data into new a generic field rather than to create several specific fields.

To account for this, when the source systems data is mapped onto the new domain model, I was hoping to record the source fieldname as an attribute, e.g.:

```
<Event>
  <Description sourceField="subject">...</Description>
  <Description sourceField="description">...</Description>
  <Description sourceField="issue">...</Description>
  <...>
</Event>
```

What would be the appropriate way to add such an attribute into the XSD? Would I need to specifically attach it to every such overloaded field, or is there a general way to allow an attribute across all elements?

Please don't point out that I should just add the extra fields into the domain model if I need to distinguish between the different data - the decision has been made, I just need to work around it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "every such overloaded field". Looks like there is only one element declaration affected: Description.

Comment: That's just one example - I have a list of all the affected fields (e.g. Description) but would still like to know if there's an easy way of enforcing the sourceField attribute universally (hundreds and hundreds of elements).

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

If all your element declarations extend from a common base type definition, then you can add the attribute to the base.

If all your element declarations include an `anyAttribute`, you can make a global attribute definition for `sourceField`. Then the validator would at least *allow* your attribute but not *require* it. And if the `anyAttribute` is `strict` or `lax` the validator will make sure the attribute's content is valid.